# Is there a possibility to get 'Last Seen' parameter for all Users in Amplitude via the API?

Tags: amplitude-analytics

I tried to find solution in Amplitude's [User Profile API](https://developers.amplitude.com/docs/user-profile-api), but it allows request this data for just one user at once, defining `user_id`.